# Что значит оператор `!!`?

Tags: javascript

```
const peekIncrementer = +!!Glide.settings.peek
```

Двойное не - что это значит?

Comment: Двойное приведет к булевому значению, а `+` к `0|1`

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема, если Вы знаете, что это отрицание? А это двойное отрицание. "!!!" - тройное отрицание. "!!!!" - четверное отрицание...

Comment: Одиночное также приведет к булевому значению.

Comment: @SeQwerMan да, но к противоположному. А два приведет к реальному.

Comment: @SeQwerMan одиночное приведет, но изменит значение на противоположное

Answer (score -1):

```
!<something>;
```

Это логическое не:

```
if !0{
<this_commend_will_be_executed>;
}
```

---

```
!!<something>;
```

Это перевод к булевому значению:

```
if !!"hello world"{<this_will_be_executed>;}
if !!""{<but_this_wont_be_executed>;}
```